# How to pull email and name from Flamingo plugin

Tags: plugins, posts, meta-value

I am trying to pull the name and email from the database and show on the front end of my website. I tried many scripts and looked on the flamingo forum as well. But couldnt find a solution.

All the data is saved in one of the `wp_postmeta`. How do I differentiate flemingo postmeta as there are multiple `postmeta`s? and how do I pull in just flemingo `_field_fullname` and `_from_email` ?
Here is a database dump

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
(5874, 1438, '_field_fullname', 'Jason'),
(5875, 1438, '_field_phone', '04112343'),
(5876, 1438, '_field_email', 'test@test.com'),
```

Thanks heaps in advance.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/

Comment: If you are certain that `_field_fullname` and `_field_email` are the meta keys populated by the plugin, then you can use [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to get the meta_value.

Comment: Hi Samuel. Thanks. Are you able to provide a script? Im extremely new to these stuff.

Comment: try something like this : `echo get_post_meta(1438, "_field_fullname", TRUE);`

Comment: @mmm It works. But how do I pull in all flamingo data without entering the meta_id?

Comment: you can use this function : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts